# TypeScript and Backbone; using className as a function?

Tags: backbone.js, typescript

I'm extending a Backbone class (View) and my class has defined className as a function to be evaluated at runtime (which is an acceptable option according the Backbone spec).

However, the index.d.ts defines className as a string only.

Is there a way I can extend to the definition to also allow className to be a function?

thanks in advance...

```
class View<TModel extends Model> extends Events {

    /**
    * Do not use, prefer TypeScript's extend functionality.
    **/
    private static extend(properties: any, classProperties?: any): any;

    constructor(options?: ViewOptions<TModel>);
    initialize(options?: ViewOptions<TModel>): void;

    /**
    * Events hash or a method returning the events hash that maps events/selectors to methods on your View.
    * For assigning events as object hash, do it like this: this.events = <any>{ "event:selector": callback, ... };
    * That works only if you set it in the constructor or the initialize method.
    **/
    events(): EventsHash;

    $(selector: string): JQuery;
    model: TModel;
    collection: Collection<TModel>;
    //template: (json, options?) => string;
    setElement(element: HTMLElement|JQuery, delegate?: boolean): View<TModel>;
    id: string;
    cid: string;
    className: string;
    tagName: string;

    el: any;
    $el: JQuery;
    setElement(element: any): View<TModel>;
    attributes: any;
    $(selector: any): JQuery;
    render(): View<TModel>;
    remove(): View<TModel>;
    make(tagName: any, attributes?: any, content?: any): any;
    delegateEvents(events?: EventsHash): any;
    delegate(eventName: string, selector: string, listener: Function): View<TModel>;
    undelegateEvents(): any;
    undelegate(eventName: string, selector?: string, listener?: Function): View<TModel>;

    _ensureElement(): void; }
```

Comment: Just modify the `.d.ts` file you have and change it to `className: () => string | string`

Comment: Thank you so much!  Is there a way to do this without modifying the .d.ts file?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. As it states in [Declaration Merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html): `"Non-function members of the interfaces must be unique. The compiler will issue an error if the interfaces both declare a non-function member of the same name"`